# Adding jQuery to XMLHttp

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

How can I add jQuery click events to a page which was loaded with XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`$.live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) method to handle items that will appear later in the pages lifetime.

```
  $("a").live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // disables all links, even links added via AJAX
  });
```

Comment: could you guid me something about $.live

Comment: but how can i combine and external function to $.live() with adding any event suppose i have a function like
function myfnc(){
alert("Done");
}
than how can i combine this to $.live on window load......

Comment: You should keep your functions out of your external pages. Keep your javascript in javascript files, html in html files, php in php files, and so on :)

Comment: i am using elastic() jquery plugin to make my textarea behaves auto height......i am implement it liek
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#textarea").elastic();
});
where #textarea is id of my textarea....so how can i implement this in $.live()

Comment: `$.live()` only works for a limit set of events: click, doubleclick, mousedown, etc. For this reason, you won't be using `$.live()` to apply `$.elastic()` to your textareas. Instead, you'll have to manually apply it after each ajax-request finishes. Look for new textareas, and apply it to them.

Comment: Your question here was "How do I add click events to dynamically loaded elements." My answer explains how - as such, if you have other issues, you should create new questions.